# The proper index for a date column -is before- another date column query

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, sequelize.js

I'm using MySQL and seqeulize.js.
I have a table with all sorts of data, and 2 Date columns, lets call them A and B.
I'm using a query to get all rows from the table where A < B.

I was wondering, which index should I configure to fit this query:
index just column A? just B? index each one alone? or use a compound index for both of them together?

Comment: You cannot index a comparison between two columns in the same table.  The best you can do is add another column which is the difference and index that.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks.